# InfoWindow not displaying address information from KML

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, kml

I'm pretty new to KML.
I have an excel spreadsheet containing a bunch of (approx. 2000) addresses.
It does not contain Lat/Long coordinates.
Each part of the address is in a separate column.
Address/Address2/City/State/Zip...etc.

Using the google maps engine I was able to generate a map with a bunch of markers on it.
I exported my map to KML via the link in google maps engine.
That resulted in placemark data that looked like this:

```
<Placemark>
    <styleUrl>#icon-503-DB4436</styleUrl>
    <name>Brun’s Apple Market</name>
    <ExtendedData>
    <Data name='ADDRESS1'><value>849 W 6th Ave.</value></Data>
    <Data name='ADDRESS2'><value></value></Data>
    <Data name='CITY'><value>Eugene</value></Data>
    <Data name='STATE'><value>OR</value></Data>
    <Data name='ZIPCODE'><value>47938</value></Data>
    <Data name='Country'><value>US</value></Data>
    <Data name='PHONE'><value></value></Data>
</ExtendedData>
<description><![CDATA[ADDRESS1: 849 W 6th Ave.<br>ADDRESS2: <br>CITY: Eugene<br>STATE: OR<br>ZIPCODE: 47938<br>Country: US<br>PHONE: ]]></description>
<address>849 W 6th Ave. Eugene OR 47938 US</address>
</Placemark>
```

The info windows contained the address and everything looked good.

I then attempted to use that KML file on my page with the google maps api.
This resulted in a map with no markers on it.
As far as I can tell that is because my placemarks lacked Lat/Long coordinates.

I looked around and found BatchGeo.com. 
I ran my spreadsheet of addresses through their online tool, created a map and exported the KML from them.
The placemark part of the KML looks like this:

```
<Placemark>
    <styleUrl>#0</styleUrl>
    <name>Brun’s Apple Market</name>
    <ExtendedData></ExtendedData>
    <address>849 W 6th St Eugene OR 47938 US</address>
    <Point>
        <coordinates>-123.10554659123,44.053497015009,0</coordinates>
    </Point>
</Placemark>
```

When I use that KML on my page with the google maps api I get my placemarks.
What I don't get is any address information in the Info Window.

When I cut and paste the ExtendedData tag from the first file into the second file, I get my address information in the InfoWindow.

I'm hoping someone out there knows:

-A way to get the ExtendedData field of the second file to have the proper data in it.

OR

-A way to get my InfoWindow to display the "address" values from the second file.

OR

-A way to get the google maps engine to put Lat/Long coordinates into the export.

OR

-Some option I had not considered to acquire a KML file in the proper format.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the `<address>` tags to `<description>` the data there will appear in the infowindow.

Comment: Doh! Yep, that was it! Thank you so much for that simple lucid response to my question. So obvious! Thank you.